# Show that the following sequence space is Complete.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

So, the goal of the question was to prove that the following is a Banach Space:

$E:= \{a = (a_k)_{k=1}^\infty : \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n}a_kx_k$ converges in $X\}$ 
equipped with the norm $||a||_E := \sup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_kx_k||$.
Where $(x_k)$ is a Schauder basis for a Banach space $X$.

Proving that the norm axioms hold is trivial, but I seem to be running into some trouble trying to prove that the space $E$ is complete. This is what I have, and I am pretty certain that it is not true:

Let ${y_n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $E$ such that $y_n \rightarrow y$. $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}y_kx_k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(y_kx_k +yx_k - yx_k) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(y_k-y)x_k + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}yx_k$, which converges in $X$ so $y$ must be in $E$.

Any hints or encouragement would be welcomed. I am now considering a sequence of sequences.

Comment: Are you sure that $E$ is a subspace of $X$? $E$ should be a subspace of the scalar field and to show that $E$ is itself complete you can try to show that $E$ is a closed subspace of the scalar field.

Comment: @UrbanPENDU, Now that I think about it, no I do not believe that $E$ is a subspace of $X$. And, yes, you are right that it is probably the scalars of the schauder basis for $X$ that is formed into a sequence itself. I will edit.

Comment: It is wrong to assume the sequence $(y_n)_n$ converges to anything. What you need to show is that the Cauchy sequence converges in the E-norm to  a member of  E....  If  $y_n=(y_{n,k})_{k\in  N},$  then for each $k,$  does $(y_{n,k})_n$  converge to some $z_k$?